# Why exponential function on p-adic numbers is meaningless?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

In the [notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/characterQ.pdf), page 3, it is said that $e^{2\pi i r y}$ is meaningless if $y$ is a general p-adic number. Why exponential function on p-adic numbers is meaningless? Thank you very much.

Comment: what is $\pi$ times a p-adic number? This doesn't make sense. Just look at the definition of a p-adic number. What he's doing in the notes is showing you a way to make this formal, by finding analogues with the real case. Or at least thats what I guess he's doing. I've not read it really.

Comment: @ChrisBirkbeck, in the [lecture notes](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~kazhdan/Notes/l.pdf), page 4, example 1.10(b), we also have $\pi$ times a p-adic number.

Comment: He has $\pi$ times $\bar{a}$ with $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}[1/p]$, so its not a p-adic number, its just a rational number isn't it? If you take a p-adic number and write it out then it looks like a power series in p and this doens't converge unless you use the p-adic norm, so it cant be a real number (in genreal)?

Comment: The trick that prof. Conrad is using is that $y$ here is never really a $p$-adic. It only gets multiplied by a rational number $2\pi i$ disappears in a way, if $ry$ makes sense as a coset in $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$, because $e^{2\pi in}=1$ for all integers $n$. But it is inherently meaningless because that $2\pi iry$ does not exist in any domain we know of.

Comment: It is essential in what I wrote in that note that $y$ is *arbitrary* in $\mathbf Q_p$. Of course the expression you write in the question makes direct sense if $y$ is rational, since $\mathbf Q$ naturally embeds into $\mathbf C$, the domain of the complex exponential function. But $p$-adic numbers that are not rational do not have "natural" embeddings into the complex numbers (even if the number is algebraic, for which there are  embeddings but more than one, hence no natural choice for the purpose of the task of creating characters of $\mathbf Q$).

Comment: @LJR:  I updated that file you linked to, in order to clear up the confusion on this point (which is now appearing on page 2 rather than page 3).

Comment: @KCd, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s not the exponential function for $p$-adic numbers that’s meaningless; rather it’s the act of multiplying the real number $\pi$ by a nonrational $p$-adic number that’s meaningless. There’s no way of multiplying a real times a $p$-adic unless one of them is rational.

On the other hand, there *is* a $p$-adic exponential function, but it has nothing to do with the case that Conrad is discussing in these notes. It’s defined by the same power series that you learned in Calculus, but when considered as a function on a $p$-adic domain (whether $\mathbb Q_p$ or a complete field extension of $\mathbb Q_p$), its domain of definition is lamentably small, that is $\exp(z)$ converges at $z$ only when $v_p(z)>1/(p-1)$, where $v_p$ is the additive $p$-adic valuation normalized so that $v_p(p)=1$. In the language of absolute values, you need $|z|_p<\bigl(|p|_p\bigr)^{1/(p-1)}$. In particular, you can’t speak of $\exp(1)$, which would be, if it existed, the $p$-adic number corresponding to $e$.

Comment: thank you very much. I still don't understand very well. For example, in $2$-adic case, why $2\pi$ is meaningless but $\frac{1}{2}\pi$ has meaning?

Comment: Is the following true? $a \pi$ is meaningless if the $p$-adic expansion of $a$ is infinite.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I think that both of $2 \pi$ and $\pi/2$ have meaning. Is this correct?

Comment: Whoops, I should have also said that there is no pi in the $p$-adic world. How would you have defined it? It’s a real number, after all, and whatever definition you might take for the real number $\pi$ will be expected to make no sense in the $p$-adic world. For instance, though you can always take an (at most quadratic) extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ to have an $i$ in it, since the $p$-adic exponential function is never $1$ on its domain of definition (except at $z=0$), there will be no possibility for a nontrivial $z$ with $\exp(z)=1$, from which you’d have hoped to extract $\pi$.